# Has anyone built ksh93, AST, or UWIN from the AT&T repo on Github, in Cygwin?

Tags: ksh, cygwin, github

Following the move of the source code from the AT&T repo to Github, has anyone
built ksh93, AST, or UWIN from it, on a Cygwin platform?

I refer to another thread on this forum:

[Is the shell ksh93 dead?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246338/is-the-shell-ksh93-dead)

In that thread, it was reported on Tue, Jan 19, 2016 by Eleftherios
Koutsofios of AT&T had moved the source code for ksh93, the AST package, and UWIN from
the AT&T repository (which was being closed, at least for public access), to
Github. In the past, ksh93, AST and UWIN users have always been able to
download source and binary directly from the AT&T respository (where it had
been maintained by David Korn and colleagues). The move from there to Github
is a fairly radical departure for long-time users of the ATT repo,
and I would like to know if anyone has successfully built binaries from the source there, 
and in particular if anyone has done so on a Cygwin platform.

As in the past I only used to download the binaries from the ATT&T site 
(and did not build from source), it would be good to know if users experienced 
in building from the source at the AT&T site have also successfully built from Github 
(which would  confirm that the Github repository for these components is
complete).

Notes: AST is the AT&T Software Technology (AST) toolkit from AT&T Research.
UWIN is a UNIX emulator that runs under MS Windows. ksh93 refers to the version of ksh that was actively maintained and developed by David Korn & colleagues at ATT until relatively recently.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't really fit the format of the site.  If you have a specific question, about a specific issue, then rephrase, but otherwise this is too broad, or too conversational.

Comment: I have now re-worded it. The specific question is in the title. It is explained further in the text. Logically, this all would have been a comment or question in the other thread referred to, but that thread has been protected.

Comment: Is there a specific problem being asked here?